# How to get 'ONLY the tweet count' from the twitter button

Tags: twitter, count

ive been looking at the http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button#build-your-own-example , they have only show how to customize the thumbnail, but i all i need it just a 'no graphic' plain text, tweet count NUMBER. and integrate it my tweet post, so it counts the tweets for my post.

Im quite noob at this, does anyone know how to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Twitter does not have a public API to surface the share count for a URL. The button uses a private method that you could use but it is likely to change at anytime and will break your button if it does.

```
https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://google.com
```

Comment: Just to mention, apparently this method is no longer supported and creates random results....I actually got fooled!

Comment: @JulienAltieri I've updated the answer with the current API Twitter appears to be using.

Comment: Cool, that's really helpful. Well, what I am looking for is to get the count of the tweets for a particular entity. Anyone with the related experience?