# Tracking ajax requests of embedded javascript files

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter, firebug, google-plus

My question comes from a practical observation: both Twitter and Google provide their sharing buttons, which include share counts on the services. Both buttons are generated with javascript, which means that an API call must be made to obtain a newest share count on the fly. And, not surprisingly, people find solutions:

Google+ count - http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/blog/google_plus_one_button_seo_count_api/

Tweet count - [How to get 'ONLY the tweet count' from the twitter button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289624/how-to-get-only-the-tweet-count-from-the-twitter-button)

I imagine the API calls can be traced with Firebug or other similar tools, but after fiddling around I could not find how. If anybody could explain how such debugging can be done, I'd appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome, there's a Network tab in Developer Tools. There you can see all requests from the current page. For Google+ count, try to find requests made to Google's domains, and check what data has been sent. If there's something like "plusone" in the request payload, then most probably it's the request by +1 script.

Here is an example from [this page](http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/blog/google_plus_one_button_seo_count_api/):

[image]

I'm sure you can do this with Firebug, too.

Comment: Thanks! I've always figured it should be there, but I could not find it. Apparently, I was not searching well enough.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't discoverer [the Firebug Net Panel](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel) yet?   (I apologize if you had, but it does meet the question's current stated requirements.)

[image]

Comment: That was the first place I looked into, but for some reason, when you test TechCrunch main page, these requests do not appear there. On individual post pages they do, though.