# PDF of current form should be created on clicking a link using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I want to save my current page in PDF format on clicking a link.

My html code

```
<a id="pdf" href="javascript:void(0)">
          Download PDF
</a>
```

I tried this code but it is not working

```
require_once('dompdf_config.inc.php'); //on including this i get a blank page
```

script in same page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#pdf").click(function(){
var html = $("body").html();
$.post( "d1.php",{ data: html});
});
});
</script>
```

d1.php contains

```
<?php
$html = $_POST['data'];
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("myCV.pdf");
?>
```

please help me in fixing it.Suggest me if there is any better solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have error reporting turned on? could there be any specific error messages that you might be getting when you see a blank page ?

Comment: you can also do a var_dump($html) on d1.php to see what is being sent to d1.php

Comment: @Maximus2012 On including this itself i get a blank page require_once('dompdf_config.inc.php');

Comment: then its possible that there might be some errors that are getting suppressed. Do you have error reporting turned on ?

Comment: Also, in your code, maybe you can use jQuery to send the POST request to d1.php so that you don't need to create another form on your current page. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: @Maximus2012 I just edit the code as you said.Getting a same blank page.

Comment: `require_once('dompdf_config.inc.php');` that file has a conflict that is causing the error. run `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of `d1.php` before the `require_once`. then you'll have your error.

Comment: Are you using require_once on d1.php ? Again, is your error reporting turned on ?

Comment: Also, now that you are using AJAX, you should use firebug(on Firefox) or Web developer extension (on IE/Chrome) to track your AJAX request to see what information is getting passed to the d1.php page. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615677/tracking-ajax-requests-of-embedded-javascript-files

Answer (score 0):

The file inclusion..

```
require_once('dompdf_config.inc.php');
```

...actually belongs at the top of d1.php.  Also, in d1.php, you have the line:

```
$html = urldecode($_POST['html']);
```

However, you don't have any form fields named "html" so I'm not sure how you're getting that data to post to that file.  And, you have a hidden form field with the id of "#hidden_form", but you seem to be intending to call the submit() function on the form, which has no id attribute.  You should add an id attribute to the form with the value of "hidden_form" (no #) if you wish to call the function this way.

This doesn't seem to be the most efficient way to do what you're wanting, but I believe if you start with these things, you'll be getting closer to where you want to be.  Once those are done, if you still have problems, turn on the error reporting as mentioned above.

Comment: I edited my code.I removed my form and sent the data through jquery to the page d1.php

Comment: the data in the post request should be an object.  `$.post(url { data:{html_data:html} } );`   Then on the backend, `$html = $_POST['html_data'];`

Comment: But, doing that doesn't serve up the PDF because it's an asynchronous post and will be looking to return JSON.  You still have to navigate to the file that it creates, so the AJAX post may not be your best option, actually, unless you create the PDF file, save it to the server, then send the link back in the AJAX response.  If you do that, you can then force a window to open to that URL when the proper response is received.